# Shader LinearGradient for autosizing TextView not working as expected

Tags: android, text

I have this autosizing `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootView">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#435f7b"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`android:text` is set programmatically.

I need to apply a `LinearGradient`:

```
Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, textView.getLineHeight()*1.1f, color1, color2, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
textView.getPaint().setShader(shader);
```

but it apparently uses wrong dimensions to calculate the text limits so it appears like this (e.g. on Android 6.0):

[image]

The layout is used as Fragment, using FragmentStatePagerAdapter and PagerAdapter.

How to make it works? It properly works on other `TextView`s set without autosizing but only with `textSize`, also in `Fragment`s.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may want to update the shader every time the line height changes.

Comment: @EugenPechanec but doing so I can face performance issues? Anyway how to do that? There isn't a method like "onPostDraw" that I can invoke which inside apply the shader? thanks

Comment: Autosizing causes a re-layout anyway so I was thinking of `View.addOnLayoutChangeListener` where you would set a new instance of the shader and call `invalidate` to cause a re-draw with the new shader.

Comment: @EugenPechanec please can you post an answer with code?

Comment: please try to use `textView.getTextSize` instead of `textView.getLineHeight()*1.1f` or check this https://blog.stylingandroid.com/gradient-text/ hope this help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code you are looking for based upon the comment from EugenPechanec.

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
textView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        int color1 = Color.RED; // Or whatever color you need.
        int color2 = Color.BLUE;
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;

        Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, tv.getLineHeight() * 1.1f, color1, color2, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        tv.getPaint().setShader(shader);
    }
});
```